# Spotfire Using Document Properties in R

Tags: r, spotfire

I know that in order to use the document properties and tables in R, you usually use the input and output parameter tabs. Is there a way to get these values just using the script, like you can in the ironpython scripts?
Thanks

Comment: No, data functions require you to define the input / output in the input / output tabs and parameter tabs.

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't**

*In an R script*, you can only use values of document properties by setting them as an input, and you can only edit them by setting them as an output.

You can find more information about R parameters [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/latest/doc/html/TIB_terr_Documentation/GUID-538F3616-D60D-4211-A340-FF4DF90E45E3.html).